# How to disable vimplugins while invoking vimdiff command

Tags: vimrc, plugin, vimdiff

I added few vim plugins like sytastic, nerdTree. They change the status line and other UI elements, which works fine while editing files.

But when I invoke `vimdiff` on 2 files, the nerdTree pane also open, the status lines are of no help. Is there anyway I can disable these plugins if I call `vimdiff` command?

Comment: there must be a cleaner way, but you could try using a dummy HOME directory so your plugins wont be found: `HOME=/home/dummy vmdiff ...`

Comment: Do you want to disable just a specific list of plugins, or all plugins? Do you want to modify your `.vimrc`, or does everything have to be done on the `vimdiff` command line?

Comment: @Gilles just the two nerdTree and syntastic for now. any way, .vimrc or commandline

Answer (score 1):

You could use this syntax, in your .vimrc:

```
if !(&diff) 
  Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
endif
```